# Jquery Jcrop plugin loads image multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jcrop

I ran into an issue with jquery Jcrop plugin

I'm using it to allow the user to crop an image, but when he/she is not satisfied with that, I set to reset the original image.

I use PHP to store the original image and cropped the image as well.

When the user hits the reset button the original image loads from the server and `jcrop` is reapplied.

But dear friends my issue is when the user clicks the "reset image" button the cropped image and original image both are displaying. there is a new  tag with no id or class is created by Jcrop and it doesn't remove when I destroy `jcrop`.

below is my code for the reset button

```
    $("#reset_crop").click(function(){
    refreshImg($("#profpic"), "files/"+fileName);
```

/*
refreshImg function adds date at Date() at the end of the image url to ignore cache. and change the src attr to the original file name.
*/

```
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    jcrop.destroy();
    $("#profpic").on('load',function(){ jcrop = createJcrop();  });

    });
```

My Jcrop settings are

```
function createJcrop(){


return  $.Jcrop("#profpic",{
            boxWidth:345,
            trueSize:[width, height],
            width:345,
            onSelect: showCoords,
            onChange: showCoords
        });
}
```

the function of the crop button is

```
    $("#crop").click(function(){
    jcrop.release();
    var newfile;
        jcrop.destroy();
        $.ajax({
        url:'crop.php',
        async:false,
        data:{fileName:fileName,width:coordinates[0],height:coordinates[1],x:coordinates[2],y:coordinates[3]},
        success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                    newfile = data;
            },
        error:function(){

                alert("something went wrong");
            }
    });

    refreshImg($("#profpic"), "files/"+newfile);
    $("#reset_crop").removeAttr('disabled');

$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");

});
```

Comment: When you rebind the image you can use jcrop.setImage(your_image); so the plugin will change the image accordingly (I think instead of release/destroy, but it must be tested)

Comment: thanks @IrvinDomininakaEdward I did as you suggested. I removed all release and destroy calls. Used setImage() but still it loads multiple images. When I crop more times the more number of <img> tags adds. It gets messy.